# Unable to set the Debug Level

Tags: debugging

I'm having trouble with the new Debug Log interface. I have set the traced entity to "Apex Class" and added the class file I want to trace. It is actually a trigger that dispatches out to the apex class.

Now, when I try and set the Debug Level to "Debug" or to "System", I just get the error message: Debug Level: No Matches Found.

I want to generate a log of my class with the debug statements I've added so I can debug the code in my class file when the trigger fires.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to create the debug level record. Click the magnifying glass, then click new to create one.

[image: Apex Debug Level Creation Example]

Comment: Thank you! I ran my code, but no log was generated for the apex class I am tracing? Shouldn't that show up in the debug logs section?

Comment: I have had issues with tracking a class before. I normally just switch it over to track the user running the class instead. Be sure that your start and end dates are set accordingly.

That being said I haven't seen anything in Winter '16 known issues, so I am sure there is a way to do it.